# what's the meaning of "entwining" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

The entwining of advocacy for services combined with the high levels of emotional support required for women to embark on the difficult pathway to recovery is changing – and not always for the best.

Comment: If I were to edit that sentence, I would remove the word "combined" as being redundant since it carries a similar meaning to "entwining."

Comment: The advocacy and support offered could be called paired, but unclear how they combine, let alone entwine.

Answer (score 1):

[entwine](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/entwine) - tie or link together

Comment: And never the twine shall meet.